# Finnish spell checker for Pages.app '09?

Tags: macos, pages, internationalization, spellcheck

Can anyone tell me where I can find a Finnish spell checker for OS X Pages '09 as it is not available through Apple?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get one at

http://voikko.sourceforge.net/ports.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good resource for Finnish spell checker files. I found good installation instructions from:

http://macmaa.com/2012/11/26/suomenkielen-oikoluvun-asennus-mountain-lioniin/