# Finnish Spell Checker for System of OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dictionary, language

I know this discussion about spell checkers for Pages, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92000/15504). 
I am searching for the files ending with `.aff` or `.dic`.
Without them, you cannot use them in system. 
My current OS X is Yosemite 10.10.2.

The manual of OS X says that in `Settings > Keyboard > Spelling > Set up ...`

> To add an additional spelling dictionary, copy the dictionary files (.aff and .dic) to the Spelling folder in your Library folder.

**Is there any standard dictionary for Finnish?**

Comment: Yes. Not correct format.

Comment: @TomGewecke It may be possible to those file types. The next thing remains to consider creating them from some existing filetype. I contacted the administrator of the project about the creation of the specific fileformats.

Comment: Just simply: Without the two supported fileformats, you cannot get system wide spell checker.

Comment: @TomGewecke Spell checking of OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Finnish language is not like others and the spell checking is more complicated than just .aff/.dic files. As Tom wrote, the solution is to use Voikko project's VoikkoSpellService (osxspell) which creates system wide spell checker for Finnish.

It works also on OS X Yosemite but the /Library folder is hidden and you have to make the Services folder if it doesn't exist. The readme in explains the rest steps to make it work.

Comment: I created the folder /Library/Services. Moved the app there. Logged out and in again. Started the app my from the folder by right clicking and open. I started TextEdit. My test data "A book is on table. Kirjae on pöydällä. Kirjava koira haukkuuu.
" It does not recognize the typos in TextEdit and not now here in Google Chrome when typing this comment.

Comment: @Masi Did you set the dictionary to Suomi in Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar?  Did you check the options for spellchecking in that menu?  See the new graphic in my answer.

Comment: @walokra /Library is not hidden.  That's user/username/Library.  In any case, there is no reason not to put this in system/library/services, which is not hidden and already exists.

Comment: @TomGewecke I do not have Spelling and Grammar in Settings -page. I check nothing.

Comment: @Masi It is not found in "Settings".  I am talking about the Edit menu in TextEdit and other apps.

Comment: @TomGewecke I did now as you instructed. The spelling fails on sentences "Koirae on tuolilla. Koirat on iloisia." and particularly does not detect mistakes in "Koirae". It warns about "Koirat" and "iloisia". It cannot detect Finnish at all. Things these sentences are English. I have adaptation set up on so it should detect language but this is very inaccurate.
It would be useful to have some shortcut to manually change spell checker, since the automatic detection does not work well with Finnish.

Comment: @Masi You have to set the spell check to Suomi, not "automatic". I don't think "automatic" works with 3rd party add-ons (and many users find it not that accurate even with Apple's dictionaries).  If Voikko is not good enough for you, best switch to Word for Mac which has its own "proofing tools" for Finnish.

Answer (score 2):

Download Voikko spell for 10.8-9 from

http://verteksi.net/lab/osxspell/

and put it in System/Library/Services  (not Library/Services or Home/Library/Services)

Go to Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar and set the dictionary to Suomi (not Automatic).

Also in Edit > Spelling and Grammar, check the items for checking and correcting spelling.

You should then see, for example in TextEdit, something like

[image]

Comment: This does not work in Yosemite. I cannot move the app to the folder /Library/Services because it does not exist in Yosemite. I will contact the current developer about this issue.

Comment: It's NOT /Library/Services, but System/Library/Services, as I said.  Please look more closely

Comment: Just a note, I had to restart my machine for the dictionary to become available.

Comment: The Finnish instructions indicate "user /Library/Services" and not "System/Library/Services" and then in the next line "~/Library/Services/..." a bit of a mess but I think the "System/Library/Services" is the correct one and works for my wife on 10.10.2, no restart was required but logout/login was done after each step.